# How can I replace \r\n with a line break when I echo?

Tags: php, nl2br

I am protecting my string using this code to insert it into the database:

```
function protect($string){

    $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);

    return $string;
}
```

I then unprotect it using this code so that I can echo it out from the database:

```
function echoprotect($string){

    $string = nl2br($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);

    return $string;
}
```

The nl2br doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. The output I get is:

> HellornrnThe content ect...

instead of:

> hello
>
> the content ect...

Comment: Is  magic_quotes_gpc active? If yes, then you should try using stripslashes before mysql_real_escape string. Try using stripslashes before nl2br.

Comment: nope, I already turned it off using the htaccess file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) manual:

> **mysql_real_escape_string()** calls MySQL's library function
>   mysql_real_escape_string, which
>   prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: \x00, **\n, \r,** \, ', "
>   and \x1a.

So `nl2br()` is ignoring the escaped \n's and \r's, methinks.

Comment: how do I reverse this when I want to echo it out?

Comment: Try reversing the order of the two statements in `echoprotect()`.

Comment: I get hellornthat was a line break instead of an actual line break, the stripslashes works but not the nl2br, If i remove the strip slashes I get exactly the same but just with slashes!

Comment: I'm going to remove this post shortly as I think it is unhelpful - I thought I was on to something, now I am just downright confused :)

Comment: Hang on - try `$string = str_replace('\\', '\', $string;` instead of `stripslashes`.

Comment: It's very odd, it works fine with nl2br("Title\r\ncontent") but as soon as I add a variable it stops working!

Comment: Now it's just getting annoying!! I found this code: preg_replace('/\v+|\\\[rn]/','<br/>',$content); but this moves a line down two lines. How do I fix this!?

Comment: @Cameron - I'm retarded when it comes to regexes. I would suggest posting that as another question.